# Highlight Invalid Email Addresses in Excel Document

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, email-validation

I'm looking for a formula to use within an Excel document that will highlight and/or in some visual way indicate if an email address entry is invalid. I've looked at the following [excel email validation formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482403/excel-email-validation-formula) however, the aforementioned is only valid when entering new data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean _"only valid when entering new data"_, if you want to have visual way, you can just apply that formula in **conditional formatting**

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Prisoner,

Alternatively i use vba to do this in my sheets. This highlights the cell red if there are any funny characters in it or if it doesn't contain the correct text.

It's simple then to modify to suit your needs.

```
'=========================================================================
' Format the cell boarders when the info needs to be corrected or updated
'=========================================================================
Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
Set ThisSheet = Worksheets("Namelist")
Dim lRow As Long
Dim emailRng As Range
Dim Cell As Range


With ThisSheet

' Flags cells where the Email field contains invalid characters
lRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set emailRng = ThisSheet.Range("A2:A" & lRow)

    For Each Cell In emailRng
        If Cell.Value = "," _
            Or Cell.Value = " " _
            Or Cell.Value = "wd" _
            Or Cell.Value = "" _
            Or Not Cell.Find("<") Is Nothing _
            Or Not Cell.Find(">") Is Nothing _
            Or Not Cell.Find(":") Is Nothing _
            Or Not Cell.Find(" ") Is Nothing _
            Or Cell.Find("@") Is Nothing _
            Or Cell.Find(".com") Is Nothing And Cell.Find(".co.za") Is Nothing Then
            Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed

            Else:
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        End If
    Next
```